# Filter on association id with Doctrine querybuilder

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, associations, query-builder

I am using QueryBuilder to write a method in a repository. I want to make a `where` statement against an association the entity has **but without needing to join on the entity**.

Normally if I was using regular sql I would just do something like

```
select * from entity where entity.assocId=5
```

But with doctrine I don’t have a field for the association's Id because it's mapped as the actual entity on that column.

So I think I need to do this to achieve the same thing:

```
$qb->innerJoin(‘e.associatedEntity', ‘ae', Query\Expr\Join::ON);
$qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq(‘ae.id’, $id));
```

Which implies I need to do a `join` on every entity I want to filter against, even if it's just the Id which seems **way more expensive** an operation than it should be.

So is there a way to filter by the value in the association column without needing to join the entity?

Answer (score 10):

As of 2.4 Doctrine provides a [DQL function](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) called `IDENTITY()` that returns the FK value for an association column. I found an example use [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20594239/1469797).

Furthermore you can mix querybuilder and DQL so, it turns out, the solution to my problem is surprisingly simple.

```
$qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('IDENTITY(ae.associatedEntity)', $id));
```