# Query builder select entity relation id

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have some query and I need in select block select id relation entity, how can I do it without some join, like in SQL? In example I add leftJoin but I want understand it's possible without join like `lsc.serviceCompany.id` or how ?

```
        $qb
        ->select('
            ser_com.id as serviceCompanyId 
        ')
        ->from('AppBundle:LocationServiceCompany', 'lsc')
        ->leftJoin('lsc.serviceCompany', 'ser_com')
        ->where('lsc.serviceCompany = :sc')
        ->setParameter('sc', $serviceCompany);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$qb->select(IDENTITY(lsc.serviceCompany)) (...)
```

Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913150/how-to-get-an-id-without-join-in-doctrine2)